# React-Native-Expo: On login, setState

Tags: react-native, expo, state, setstate

On initial build or on forced restart of the app, the first user login does not update state. When a code change is made and it re-freshes the app, user login updates state in the expected manner.

This is the initial build console.log("stateUser", stateUser) :

```
stateUser
```

This is the refreshed console.log("stateUser", stateUser)  :

```
stateUser Array [
 Object {
"email": "this@email.com",
"id": 4,
"password": "",
"userToken": "devToken",
"username": "a",
   },
]
```

This is my setState call which is nested inside of a React.useMemo():

```
  const authContext = React.useMemo(() => ({
signIn: async (foundUser) => {
  // console.log(foundUser);
  userInfo = foundUser;

  const userToken = String(foundUser[0].userToken);
  const userName = foundUser[0].username;

  
  foundUserState = foundUser;
  setStateUser(foundUserState);

  loginStateUpdater(foundUser);
  // console.log(foundUser);
  // console.log("aaaaaa", stateUser, "this is the stateUser")

  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("userToken", userToken);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  // console.log('user token: ', userToken);
  dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", id: userName, token: userToken });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to ditch AsyncStorage and move to something secure. I used Firebase Auth